# How to solve HTML form action issues in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer

```
<form action="Filter.php" method="post" id="searchForm" onsubmit = "return validate(this);">

........
........

</form>

<input type="submit" name="find" id = "find" value="search" form = 'searchForm' /> 

<script>
function validate(form) {   
            var Number = document.getElementById("Number").value;   
            var value1=document.getElementById("value1").value;
            var value2= document.getElementById("value2").value;    
            var valid = true;
            if(Number== ""){
                valid = false;
                alert("Number need to be specified!");
            }
            if(value2!= ""){
                if(value1== ""){
                    valid = false;
                    alert("Value need to be selected!");
                }
            }

            return valid;
        }

</script>
```

I have a  to go Filter.php page but when button click, it go to Filter.php page in all browsers except IE 11 ? in IE 11, showing no error and didn't go to Filter.php also. Please help me for any suggestion, how should I do to go the another page properly in IE browser ?

Comment: move the submit button inside form

Comment: @gvmani Thank you